# scons visual studio express 2012 build not work

Tags: visual-c++, express, scons

I just look at documentation - [scons simple example](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/c258.html#AEN263) and it does not work for me.

First file: `main.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Second file: SCons `SConstruct`

```
Program('main.cpp')
```

Result:

```
 scons: Reading SConscript files ... 
 scons: done reading SConscript
 files. scons: Building targets ...
 cl /Fomain.obj /c main.cpp /TP /nologo
 "cl" is not an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
 scons: *** [main.obj] Error 1 scons:
 building terminated because of errors.
```

I tried this on Window 7 with Visual Studio Express 2012, scons 2.3
Any help?

Comment: SCons cant find the compiler, either it is not installed, or it is not in the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I create environment myself all works.

```
env = Environment(ENV = {'PATH' : os.environ['PATH'], \
            'INCLUDE' : 'c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\\VC\\include\\;c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\8.0\\Include\um\\;c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\8.0\\Include\\shared\\', \
            'LIB' : 'c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\\VC\\lib\\;c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\8.0\\Lib\\win8\\um\\x86\\'})
```

Also if build from cmd.exe, before call scons call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\vcvars32", and if building with scons from visual studio NMAKE do it for you.